# magento 2 Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory::getLabel() must be of the type string

Tags: product, category, product-images, magento2.3

In **custom theme** And **category page** show this error-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory::getLabel() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/html/.....
```

[image]

1 product is added that's why in image show "1 items".

Run all commands upgrade,indexing,caching,deploy,rename var folder still getting this error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally,I solved,the problem is `etc/view.xml` I didn't create while making custom theme.

When I add file **`(view.xml)`** at this location

```
app/design/frontend/Theme/theme/etc/
```

The problem is solved.

Comment: Fixed for me! I thought it should inherit its parent theme view.xml though...?

Comment: @00-BBB Same here. Do you know what is the reason, the the child theme does not use the parents file (view.xml)?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, when an image is retrieving from outside the frontend scope (sending emails via cron, etc) - make sure you are loading design area configs. E.g.:
in .phtml:

```
<?= $block->getImage($_product, 'product_thumbnail_image', ['class' => 'photo image'])->toHtml() ?>
```

in block:

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder
     */
    private $imageBuilder;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\AreaList
     */
    private $areaList;

    /**
     * ImageProvider constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder $imageBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\AreaList             $areaList
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder $imageBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\App\AreaList $areaList
    ) {
        $this->imageBuilder = $imageBuilder;
        $this->areaList = $areaList;
    }

    public function getImage(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $imageId,
        $attributes = []
    ) {
        //make sure to load the design part of configuration.
        $this->areaList->getArea(Area::AREA_FRONTEND)
            ->load(Area::PART_DESIGN);
        //when the design part is loaded - simply call native image builder - 
        return $this->imageBuilder->create($product, $imageId, $attributes);
    }
```

Comment: This was the one for me also when creating XLSX files with images for download, that view.xml does not seem to get read correctly without the area set! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is etc/view.xml, it helped me insert code in - app/design/frontend///etc/view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>110</width>
                <height>160</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="customer_account_my_tags_tag_view" type="small_image">
                <width>100</width>
                <height>100</height>
            </image>
            <image id="customer_account_product_review_page" type="image">
                <width>285</width>
                <height>285</height>
            </image>
            <image id="customer_shared_wishlist" type="small_image">
                <width>113</width>
                <height>113</height>
            </image>
            <image id="gift_messages_checkout_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="gift_messages_checkout_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>100</width>
                <height>100</height>
            </image>
            <image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>78</width>
                <height>78</height>
            </image>
            <image id="new_products_content_widget_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="new_products_content_widget_list" type="small_image">
                <width>270</width>
                <height>270</height>
            </image>
            <image id="new_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>78</width>
                <height>78</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_base_image" type="image">
                <width>265</width>
                <height>265</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_comparison_list" type="small_image">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image"/>
            <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
                <width>700</width>
                <height>700</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
                <width>90</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_swatch_image_large" type="image"/>
            <image id="product_swatch_image_medium" type="image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_swatch_image_small" type="thumbnail">
                <width>88</width>
                <height>110</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
                <width>700</width>
                <height>700</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
                <width>700</width>
                <height>700</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_more_views" type="thumbnail">
                <width>90</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_stock_alert_email_product_image" type="small_image">
                <width>76</width>
                <height>76</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>135</width>
                <height>135</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_thumbnail_image" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_images_names_widget" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_images_only_widget" type="thumbnail">
                <width>76</width>
                <height>76</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>270</width>
                <height>207</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_names_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>76</width>
                <height>76</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>270</width>
                <height>270</height>
            </image>
            <image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="review_page_product_image" type="small_image">
                <width>285</width>
                <height>285</height>
            </image>
            <image id="rss_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="sendfriend_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="shared_wishlist_email" type="small_image">
                <width>135</width>
                <height>135</height>
            </image>
            <image id="side_column_widget_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="upsell_products_list" type="small_image">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="wishlist_sidebar_block" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="wishlist_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>113</width>
                <height>113</height>
            </image>
            <image id="wishlist_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
    <vars module="Magento_Catalog">

        <!-- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start -->
        <var name="gallery">
            <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
            <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Gallery navigation loop (true/false) -->
            <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false) -->
            <var name="arrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
            <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
            <var name="allowfullscreen">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
            <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->
            <var name="navarrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides arrows(true/false) -->
            <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
            <var name="transition">
                <var name="effect">slide
                </var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
            </var>
            <var name="fullscreen">
                <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
                <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation loop (true/false/null) -->
                <var name="arrows">false
                </var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview in fullscreen (true/false/null) -->
                <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title in fullscreen(true/false) -->
                <var name="navdir">horizontal
                </var> <!--Sliding direction of thumbnails in fullscreen(horizontal/vertical)  -->
                <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
                <var name="transition">
                    <var name="effect">dissolve
                    </var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                    <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>

        <var name="magnifier">
            <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
            <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
            <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
            <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
            <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
            <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
            <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
        </var>

        <var name="breakpoints">
            <var name="mobile">
                <var name="conditions">
                    <var name="max-width">767px</var>
                </var>
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="options">
                        <var name="nav">dots</var>
                    </var>
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
        <!-- end. Gallery and magnifier theme settings -->

        <var name="product_small_image_sidebar_size">100</var>  <!-- Override for small product image -->
        <var name="product_base_image_size">275</var>           <!-- Override for base product image -->
        <var name="product_base_image_icon_size">48</var>       <!-- Base product image icon size -->

        <var name="product_list_image_size">166</var>           <!-- New Product image size used in product list -->
        <var name="product_zoom_image_size">370</var>           <!-- New Product image size used for zooming -->

        <var name="product_image_white_borders">1</var>
    </vars>
    <vars module="Magento_Bundle">
        <var name="product_summary_image_size">58</var>         <!-- New Product image size used for summary block-->
    </vars>
    <vars module="Js_Bundle">
        <var name="bundle_size">1MB</var>
    </vars>
    <exclude>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.min.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.details.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.details.min.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.hoverIntent.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::requirejs/require.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::requirejs/text.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::date-format-normalizer.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::legacy-build.min.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/captcha.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/dropdown_old.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/list.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/loader_old.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/webapi.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/zoom.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/translate-inline-vde.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/requirejs/mixins.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/requirejs/static.js</item>
        <item type="file">Magento_Customer::js/zxcvbn.js</item>
        <item type="file">Magento_Catalog::js/zoom.js</item>
        <item type="file">Magento_Ui::js/lib/step-wizard.js</item>
        <item type="file">Magento_Ui::js/form/element/ui-select.js</item>
        <item type="file">Magento_Ui::js/form/element/file-uploader.js</item>
        <item type="file">Magento_Ui::js/form/components/insert.js</item>
        <item type="file">Magento_Ui::js/form/components/insert-listing.js</item>
        <item type="directory">Magento_Ui::js/timeline</item>
        <item type="directory">Magento_Ui::js/grid</item>
        <item type="directory">Magento_Ui::js/dynamic-rows</item>
        <item type="directory">Magento_Ui::templates/timeline</item>
        <item type="directory">Magento_Ui::templates/grid</item>
        <item type="directory">Magento_Ui::templates/dynamic-rows</item>
        <item type="directory">Magento_Swagger::swagger-ui</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::modernizr</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::tiny_mce</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::varien</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/editableMultiselect</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/jstree</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/fileUploader</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::css</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::lib</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::extjs</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::prototype</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::scriptaculous</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::less</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::mage/adminhtml</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::mage/backend</item>
    </exclude>
</view>
```

or delete file - etc/view.xml

Answer (score 0):

The above regarding etc/view.xml didn't work for me.

Not a permanent solution but If it's for LOCAL development purposes only, and you want a quick way to get the site back up and running, you can simply just go to the location it's referencing in the error and comment out the line number.

e.g. vendor/magento/module-catalog/block/product/ImageFactory.php

```
    $data = [
        'data' => [
            'template' => 'Magento_Catalog::product/image_with_borders.phtml',
            'image_url' => $imageAsset->getUrl(),
            'width' => $imageMiscParams['image_width'],
            'height' => $imageMiscParams['image_height'],
            //'label' => $this->getLabel($product, $imageMiscParams['image_type']),
            'ratio' => $this->getRatio($imageMiscParams['image_width'] ?? 0, $imageMiscParams['image_height'] ?? 0),
            'custom_attributes' => $this->filterCustomAttributes($attributes),
            'class' => $this->getClass($attributes),
            'product_id' => $product->getId()
        ],
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for this error can be that **Magento thinks your theme is virtual when it's not**. Check the `theme` table for your current theme and look at the value of the `type` column. If it's set to 1, set it to 0 and clear all caches.

This issue can happen on development envrionements where you set a custom theme for a store in config.php before creating theme files. Magento not finding any files thinks your theme isn't a physical one and set the type to "1" automatically.

More on this here : https://www.naguel.com/magento-virtual-themes-or-why-theme-changes-dont-show-up-in-the-front-end/