# reindex command generates error: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory::getLabel()

Tags: product-images, magento2.3.4, reindex

When I run reindex command `bin/magento index:reindex catalog_data_exporter_categories`
I get the following error on console.

Argument 2 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory::getLabel()

Kindly find the attached image.

[image]

I referred this [LINK](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266282/magento-2-uncaught-typeerror-argument-2-passed-to-magento-catalog-block-product), but I didn't got any solution.

Kindly guide me if anyone faced this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: At a glance, its seems that error was occurred due to passing wrong argument into Magezon PageBuilder extension. Hope you can make sure by comparing the code of Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image Constructor arguments.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey chris, hope you are doing well.**

This is the issue related to theme.
try this,

```
$collection = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');


$collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left')
```

The method `addAttributeToFilter()` is expecting the 2nd parameter `$condition` to be an array or null, but the theme obviously hasn't been updated. I've changed it from

```
**$collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left')**

to...  note 1 -> [1]

**addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', [1], 'left')**
```

This works:)

Comment: where do u want me to change this code

Comment: I am getting this too after upgrading! However, if I change the theme used (Content -> Design -> Config) I can successfully view my site!

Comment: i didn't get u where should i wat to change. can u please guide me