# How to render related products block using a php script?

Tags: magento2, related-products

I've created the below code, but it looks like I'm missing something. Can you help please?

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager $objectManager */
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$pageFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory');

$productFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
$product = $productFactory->create()->load(143767);
$registry->register('product', $product);
$resultRedirect = $pageFactory->create();

echo $resultRedirect->getLayout()
    ->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related")
    ->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml")
    ->setData('type', 'related')
    ->toHtml();
```

(Magento version is 2.4.2). The problem is:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory::getLabel() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ImageFactory.php on line 168 and defined in /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ImageFactory.php:117
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ImageFactory.php(168): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory-&gt;getLabel()
#1 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ImageFactory/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory-&gt;create()
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ImageBuilder.php(135): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory\Interceptor-&gt;create()
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php(518): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder-&gt;create()
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml(216): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Abstr in /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ImageFactory.php on line 117
```

Comment: It is likely not successfully loading the product in the line `$product = $productFactory->create()->load(143767);`. Are you sure you have a product with this id?

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure I have a product with this id because I can get any attributes of the product:
`$product = $productFactory->create()->load(143767);`

`echo $product->getSku(); // G08333300145G`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/329169/81352 . The below code works fine.

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager $objectManager */
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$areaList = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\AreaList');
$areaList->getArea(Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND)->load(Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_DESIGN);

$registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$pageFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory');

$productFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
$product = $productFactory->create()->load(143767);
$registry->register('product', $product);
$resultRedirect = $pageFactory->create();

echo $resultRedirect->getLayout()
    ->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related")
    ->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml")
    ->setData('type', 'related')
    ->toHtml();
```